# MinIO fails to start as systemctl service but manual start using command line works

Tags: minio, rocky-os

I am trying to setup MinIO cluster (4 VMs) using the guide here https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/install-deploy-manage/deploy-minio-multi-node-multi-drive.html
All the VMs are identical in configuration. All the VMs have one drive mounted at /data/minio.
OS: Rocky Linux release 8.7 (Green Obsidian). Firewall is open for ports 8080 and 8081. Trying to setup minio without TLS certificate.

1. Installed the MinIO Binary on Each Node
   `wget https://dl.min.io/server/minio/release/linux-amd64/archive/minio-20230407052858.0.0.x86_64.rpm -O minio.rpm`
   `sudo dnf install minio.rpm`
2. systemd Service File
   I have not edited the service file (/etc/systemd/system/minio.service) that was created by the above RPM installation and left it as such.
3. Create the Service Environment File
   As root, I created this file /etc/default/minio with the following contents

> MINIO_VOLUMES="http://minio{1...4}.domain.com:8080/data/minio"
> MINIO_OPTS="--address :8080 --console-address :8081"
> MINIO_ROOT_USER=minioadmin
> MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
> MINIO_SERVER_URL="http://minio1.domain.com:8080"

4. Tried to start the service
   `systemctl start minio.service`

Journalctl does not give any error message apart from the following:
minio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
minio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Manual start: when i source the above env file and start the server '/usr/local/bin/minio server $MINIO_OPTS $MINIO_VOLUMES', it worked as i can access the minio console and can login.

Without any error messages in the journalctl, i have no clue where to start the troubleshooting. Can anyone see if i am missing something obvious please?

Comment: could this be an issue? found this in journalctl.  ERROR Unable to validate credentials inherited from the shell environment: Invalid credentials
      > Please provide correct credentials
HINT:
      Access key length should be at least 3, and secret key length at least 8 characters

Answer (score 5):

Solved it. For the benefit of others:
if the password is not at least 8 characters, then the MinIO service does not start. After changing the password to longer string, the service started as expected.

Comment: How you solved it ?